# How to group and sum arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
ar = [[5, "2014-01-27"],
[20, "2014-01-28"],
[5, "2014-01-28"],
[10, "2014-01-28"],
[15, "2014-01-29"],
[5, "2014-01-29"],
[5, "2014-01-30"],
[10, "2014-01-30"],
[5, "2014-01-30"]]
```

What I ultimately need to do is group the array items by date and sum up the numbers in the first item of each sub-array.

So output would be something like:

```
[[5, "2014-01-27"],
[35, "2014-01-28"],
[20, "2014-01-29"],
[20, "2014-01-30"]]
```

Answer (score 10):

`ar.group_by(&:last).map{ |x, y| [y.inject(0){ |sum, i| sum + i.first }, x] }`

Edit to add explanation:
We group by the last value (the date) yielding a hash:

```
{"2014-01-27"=>[[5, "2014-01-27"]], "2014-01-28"=>[[20, "2014-01-28"], [5, "2014-01-28"], [10, "2014-01-28"]], "2014-01-29"=>[[15, "2014-01-29"], [5, "2014-01-29"]], "2014-01-30"=>[[5, "2014-01-30"], [10, "2014-01-30"], [5, "2014-01-30"]]}
```

Then map that with `x` as they hash key, and `y` as the array of `[[number, date], [number, date]]` pairs.

`.inject(0)` means `sum` starts out as `0`, then we add the first item of each array (the number) to that sum until all arrays are iterated and all the numbers are added.

Then we do `[y, x]` where `x` is the hash key (the date), and `y` is the sum of all the numbers.

This method is efficient as we use inject to avoid mapping the array twice and don't have to reverse the values afterwards since we swapped their positions while mapping it.

Edit: Interestingly the benchmarks between @bjhaid and my answer are close:

```
    user     system      total        real
5.117000   0.000000   5.117000 (  5.110292)
5.632000   0.000000   5.632000 (  5.644323)
```

`1000000` iterations - my method was the slowest

Comment: To use chunk, I believe you need to sort first: `[3,3,1,3,3].chunk {|e| e}.to_a # => [[3, [3, 3]], [1, [1]], [3, [3, 3]]`

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to your code-only answer.

Comment: Your example worked better for me in my case, where I needed to group 3 objects instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = ar.group_by(&:last)
h.keys.each{|k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:first).inject(:+)}
h.map(&:reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {}
ar.map{|v,date| result[date] ||= 0; result[date] += v}
```

then you get a hash with the keys being the dates and the values being the sums, do you really need result to be an array? it looks like you need a hash, but I don't know the context

maybe you don't even have to do this in ruby, if this all comes from a db you can group and sum right with the query

Comment: Result doesn't necessarily have to be an array, a hash is fine. But your example seems to only output sums...no dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
ar.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,hash| hash[x[1]] += x[0] }.map(&:reverse)
=> [[5, "2014-01-27"], [35, "2014-01-28"], [20, "2014-01-29"], [20, "2014-01-30"]]
```

#### Explained

The first portion uses [Hash.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) as an object supplied to [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to generate a `Hash`, which sets its keys to the dates(second index of the array) and the values to the sum of the first index of the array

```
[29] pry(main)> ar.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,hash| hash[x[1]] += x[0] }
=> {"2014-01-27"=>5, "2014-01-28"=>35, "2014-01-29"=>20, "2014-01-30"=>20}
```

The second portion uses [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), which treats each `key`, `value` pair from the hash as an array which is yielded to the block/proc, [Array#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse) is called on each yielded pair to reverse and generate the final array

```
[30] pry(main)> {"2014-01-27"=>5, "2014-01-28"=>35, "2014-01-29"=>20, "2014-01-30"=>20}.map(&:reverse)
=> [[5, "2014-01-27"], [35, "2014-01-28"], [20, "2014-01-29"], [20, "2014-01-30"]]
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @sawa's solution, which uses `group_by`, but here's another way that helps illustrate the diversity of approaches that are possible here.

First convert the array to a hash, with dates as keys

```
h = ar.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |(x,d),h| h[d] << x }
  # => {"2014-01-27"=>[5],
  #     "2014-01-28"=>[20, 5, 10],
  #     "2014-01-29"=>[15, 5],
```

Next, replace each value (array) in this hash with the sum of its elements:

```
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].reduce(:+) }
  #   => ["2014-01-27", "2014-01-28", "2014-01-29", "2014-01-30"]
  # h => {"2014-01-27"=>5 , "2014-01-28"=>35,
  #       "2014-01-29"=>20, "2014-01-30"=>20}
```

Notice that this expression returns an array of the keys, but the hash `h` now has the desired values.  For that reason, we cannot chain to the final statement:

```
h.map(&:reverse).sort_by(&:first)
  # => [[ 5, "2014-01-27"], [35, "2014-01-28"],
  #     [20, "2014-01-29"], [20, "2014-01-30"]]
```

One of the reasons I wrote it this way is encourage you to consider using the hash `g` as your final result, rather than another array.  (This is also the value of `h` after the first two lines in @sawa's solution).  Consider whether that might make more sense in subsequent operations in your code.

Most of this is straightforward, but the first `each with object` requires a bit of explanation.  The `object` is a hash, represented in the block by the local variable `h`.  This hash is created by:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

which makes the default value an empty array.  The first time through the block, `d => "2014-01-27"`.  As the hash is initially empty, it has no key `"2014-01-27"`.  As a result, `h["2014-01-27"]` is assigned the default value `[]`, after which `h["2014-01-27"] << 5`, resulting in `h => {"2014-01-27" => 5}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ar.group_by(&:last).map{ |d,g| [g.map(&:first).inject(:+), d] }
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors if you add some explantion for your intention.

Answer (score 0):

I find the following somewhat less esoteric

```
ar.group_by(&:last).map {|k, v| [v.map {|e| e[0]}.sum, k]}
```