# How do I group arrays by the first 2 values and sum their corresponding number in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I came across this question [How to group and sum arrays in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506965/how-to-group-and-sum-arrays-in-ruby) and was wondering how to apply it to my current problem at hand.

I have a multidimensional array with values as follows:

```
[[0,0,5],
[0,0,10],
[1,0,4],
[1,0,8],
[1,2,5],
[1,2,6]]
```

and I need to sum the 3rd value in each sub-array according to the 1st and 2nd values to get this output:

```
[[0,0,15], [1,0,12], [1,2,11]]
```

Any idea how to get this done? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
input.group_by { |e| e.take(2) }
     .map { |k, vals| [*k, vals.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }
#⇒ [[0, 0, 15], [1, 0, 12], [1, 2, 11]]
```

or

```
input.group_by { |e| e.take(2) }
     .map { |k, vals| [k, vals.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }.to_h
#⇒ {[0, 0]=>15, [1, 0]=>12, [1, 2]=>11}
```

Used here:

- [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)
- [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- [`Array#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, i'm a little new to Ruby so could you explain your code?

Comment: I put links to the documentation, though I don’t see what you expect me to explain? Try to execute the code above in console step by step, see what it resulted in and understand how it works. It worth 100 plain English explanations.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `group_by`

```
inputs.group_by{|x| [x[0], x[1]]}.map{|k, v| [*k, v.map{|z| z[2]}.inject(:+)] }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the formula, i'm a little new to Ruby so could you explain your code?